# Using scoring to find customers

Tags: algorithm, taxonomy, scoring

I have a site where customers purchase items that are tagged with a variety of taxonomy terms. I want to create a group of customers who might be interested in the same items by considering the tags associated with purchases they've made. Rather than comparing a list of tags for each customer each time I want to build the group, I'm wondering if I can use some type of scoring to solve the problem.

The way I'm thinking about it, each tag would have some unique number assigned to it. When I perform a scoring operation it would render a number that could only be achieved by combining a specific set of tags.

I could update a customer's "score" periodically so that it remains relevant.

Am I on the right track? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by score?

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean, but it won't work this way: If I have Red = 1, Blue = 2, Green = 3 and Yellow = 4, I could look at the sum of any combination. The problem is it won't be unique. Red and Blue would be 3 which is also Green. If I can get the result to be 1 unique number (score) then I can compare scores instead of each individual tag.

Comment: Why sum and not just a list?

Comment: I definitely can't use the sum (I was just giving a simple example), but I need some type of operation that when you feed it a list of numbers, the result is a number that can only be derived using one combination of input numbers. Ultimately, the goal is to compare scores. So if Customer A has a 324 and customer B has a 324, I know they've purchased items with the same tags

Comment: Concatenate and sort? Red+Blue = 12, Yellow+Blue+Green = 423, etc. Concatenate will be unique, sort will mean not "too unique" Red+Blue = Blue+Red. The only thing you need to make sure is that each tag is unique. So Magenta can't be like 12 as that is Red+Blue.

Comment: I thought of concatenating, but using your example, I may have a tag = 12 so it would be limited. The system has thousands of tags. That's my problem.

Comment: Concatenating as a list rather than as a number would be (1,2) versus 12 which makes that unique.

Comment: @UmarFarooq you might be onto something. This might work.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the problem looks much more like a clustering or recommendation problem. I am not sure if those tags are enough of an information to use clustering or recommendation tough.

Your idea of the score doesn't look promising to me, because the same sum could be achieved in several ways, if those numbers aren't carefully enough chosen.

What I would suggest you:

You can store tags for each user. When some user purchases a new item, you will add the tags of the item to the user's tags. On periodical time you will update the users profiles. Let's say we have users A and B. If at the time of the update the similarity between A and B is greater than some threshold, you will add a relation between the users which will indicate that the two users are similar. If it's lower you will remove the relation (if previously they were related). The similarity could be either a number of common tags or `num_common_tags / num_of_tags_assigned_either_in_A_or_B`.

Later on, when you will want to get users with particular set of tags, you will just do a query which checks which users have that set of tags. Also you can check for similar users to given user, just by looking up which users are linked with the user in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a unique power of two to each tag, then you can sum the values corresponding to the tags, and users with the exact same sets of tags will get identical values.

```
red = 1
green = 2
blue = 4
yellow = 8
```

For example, only customers who have the set of `{ red, blue }` will have a value of 5.

This is essentially using a bitmap to represent a set.  The drawback is that if you have many tags, you'll quickly run out of integers.  For example, if your (unsigned) integer type is four bytes, you'd be limited to 32 tags.  There are libraries and classes that let you represent much larger bitsets, but, at that point, it's probably worth considering other approaches.

Another problem with this approach is that it doesn't help you cluster members that are similar but not identical.